# Do not send SMS at night

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

Is it possible to not send SMS from 9 PM to 9 AM, and send out those messages the next morning. The SMS is being sent out via Journey.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the blackout window in the Delivery Options tab of the SMS activity or use the Wait Until Date activity to do not send the SMS until the next morning.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solves my question.

Comment: This is only partially correct. If you set the Blackout in Journey Builder, SMS messages will not send during the blackout. But in addition, SMS messages will not queue.

NOTE In Journey Builder, a send blackout window completely prevents messages from sending. Messages don’t queue for sending at later time. Send blackouts set in Journey Builder are independent of send blackouts set in MobileConnect. Blackouts set in MobileConnect Setup are not respected.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_send_blackouts.htm&type=5